# Bash script escaping quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters

I'm writing a bash script to find all the images in the folder and find if they have corrupt endings with ImageMagick.

This is the command I'm trying to automate:

```
identify -verbose *.jpg 2>&1 | grep "Corrupt" | egrep -o "([\`].*[\'])"
```

The issue I'm having is with storing the identify command into a variable.

There are multiple types of quotes that are present in the command I keep getting an error **line 8: corrupt: command not found**

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will search for all images that are broken and put them into a text file

FILES="*.jpg"

for f in $FILES
do
  corrupt = "identify -verbose \"$f\" 2>&1 | grep \"Corrupt\" | egrep -o \"([\`].*[\'])\""

  if [ -z "$corrupt" ]
  then
    echo $corrupt
  else
    echo  "not corrupt"
  fi
done
```

Is there a way to escape that command correctly?

UPDATE:

Some progress:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will search for all images that are broken and put them into a text file

FILES="*.jpg"

for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f"
  corrupt="identify -verbose $f 2>&1 | grep \"Corrupt\" | egrep -o \"([\`].*[\'])\""

  if [ -z "$corrupt" ]
  then
    echo $corrupt
  else
    echo  "not corrupt"    
  fi

done
```

This no longer throws an error, but it looks like it just stores the variable as a string.

How can I run this command?

UPDATE: Some progress. Now the command is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will search for all images that are broken and put them into a text file

FILES="*.jpg"

for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f"

  corrupt=`identify -verbose $f | grep \"Corrupt\" | egrep -o \"([\`].*[\'])\"`

  $corrupt

  if [ -z "$corrupt" ]
  then
    echo $corrupt
  else
    echo  "not corrupt"    
  fi

done
```

But the output of pipes is separate:

```
Processing sdfsd.jpg
identify-im6.q16: Premature end of JPEG file `sdfsd.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/387.
identify-im6.q16: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `sdfsd.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/387.
```

I just need the final **`sdfsd.jpg'** string.

Comment: @Quasímodo Did I misspell something? I tested the command separately and it's working correctly. I'm new to bash scripting so I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: `corrupt="identify..."` sets the variable to the given literal value, just like `FILES="*.jpg"`. I think you're looking for command substitution: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks! I already figured out the backticks will work better. Now the pipes are not running at the same time for some reason. Is there a way to run them all at the same time as the original command so I could get the final string?

Comment: If you're learning then quickly unlearn backticks and instead use `$( ... )` for command substitution

Comment: @roaima already did. Unfortunately still cannot capture the final output of the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a way of identifying corrupt images.  It's easy to query the `identify` tool for its exit-status to see whether it managed to identify the image file or not.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for name in *.jpg; do
    if identify -regard-warnings -- "$name" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Ok: %s\n' "$name"
    else
        printf 'Corrupt: %s\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

The above uses the exit-status of `identify` to determine whether the file was corrupt or not. [The `-regard-warnings` option](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#regard-warnings) escalates the warnings you mention into errors turn, which makes them affect the exit-status of the utility.

You very seldom need to store actual globbing patterns in variables. You can often get a utility's success/failure status by testing its exit-status like what we show above without parsing the tool's output.

For older ImageMagick releases (I'm using 6.9.12.19), use `convert` instead of `identify`.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for name in *.jpg; do
    if convert -regard-warnings -- "$name" - >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Ok: %s\n' "$name"
    else
        printf 'Corrupt: %s\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

The above loop tries to convert each image, and if it fails to process an image file, it is detected by the `if` statement.  We discard the result of the conversion operation.

Comment: Thanks, but this is failing on my test files. Here is a test file: https://ufile.io/sz8gn4e8

Comment: @KalvinKlien See updated answer.

Comment: This still does not trigger on test files.

Comment: @KalvinKlien This identifies the file that you link to as corrupt.

Comment: This does not work. Here's the output: https://imgur.com/a/QMsamvi 5 of those files are corrupt.

Comment: @KalvinKlien Are you actually running the code in the answer, with `-regard-warnings`? I can confidently say that the `sdfsd.jpg` image is identified as corrupt.

Comment: Here is the script copied from your post: https://imgur.com/a/fqCnFZf Output: https://imgur.com/a/LWIFYce

Comment: @they I copy paste your code, downloaded the image, ran the script and it gives "OK".

Comment: @KalvinKlien Well, what can I say? It works for me with ImageMagick 6.9.12.19.

Comment: @they I'm running: Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib

Comment: I tried on CentOS machine and it's also not working :( sucks.

Comment: @KalvinKlien See added bit.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! This is not actually converting the file correct?

Comment: @KalvinKlien It is converting the image, but the converted image is thrown away (`-` means write the result to standard output, and we redirect this to `/dev/null`).  The original image files are not modified.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll keep going on this task. There's a bunch of stuff I still need to do like logging and full file path on the server. This is so I could delete broken images and then delete them from DB.

Comment: @they grrrrr. I'm starting to test more files and some of the files are not detected. Example: https://ufile.io/f/9sg4y

Comment: @KalvinKlien You will notice that neither of these files are detected as corrupt by `identify -verbose` either. I wonder whether they were saved in their truncated state.  Both contains a creator comment `CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0`.

Comment: @they Hmmm...its possible I saved them after I downloaded them somehow. I'll check more files later.

Comment: @they I figured it out, I needed to pull samples from server itself because Cloudflare was modifying the files, it was "fixing" them. Thanks for all the help. The script works correctly!